# Integrating jquery-mobile with struts2

Tags: jquery-mobile, struts2

I am trying to integrate struts2 with jquery-mobile. I used the jquery-mobile-struts plugin, the latest one. But while compiling I am getting tag rendering exceptions. Has anyone tried integrating struts2 and jquery mobile? Are there any sites or tutorials for this?

Any suggestion would be of great help!!

Thanks
Anil

Comment: not sure, but i believe there will not be difference the way it works as normal jquery plugin and only difference shd be in the rendering of UI

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to probably not use the plugin.

Simply use jQuery in your jsp's as you would with any web page.  When you need a url, always be sure to use the struts url tag to construct it, that way the application will remain portable (this avoids avoid hard coding urls).

If you follow this advice you can keep struts2 questions and jquery/jquery-mobile questions independent and as a result find answers (or get answers on StackOverflow) much more quickly.

Applying a tag library over a JS library reduces functionality and transparency. At that costs you get predetermined functionality provided by the tags, which is probably most appropriate to someone who can not work with JS/jQuery directly.

Comment: +1 for suggesting using JQuery, which will provide more flexibility and ease of use